# jQuery Deferred promise then

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to the JavaScript Promises and having tough time grasping the concept. It seemed I finally understood, but can't seem to get it working.

Here's a simple try:

```
first = function(){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    console.log("first running")
    return deferred.promise();
}

second = function(){
    console.log("second running..sigh..");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    first().then(second);

});
```

Second is not being called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the second function to be called, you need to resolve the deferred returned from the first function:

```
first = function(){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    console.log("first running");
    deferred.resolve();  // <----------resolve the deferred
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

You can also resolve it with arguments so that whatever its resolved with, will be passed as arguments to your second function.  Here's a fiddle that adds a slight delay to the resolve so it mimics asynchronous behavior and resolves with actual data:

http://jsfiddle.net/1k6tLev8/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can think a **[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** as a task that, in future, will be processed and a result will be returned to all functions that follow the deferred object.

Promises can have 3 + 1 states:

1. **Pending** (The task isn't processed yet)
2. **FullFilled** or **Resolved** (Correctly Processed)
3. **Rejected** (Processed but failed)
4. **Settled** (indicates that the task is already processed.)

---

```js
var doSomethingAsync = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('Hello World');

    // OR
    
    // reject('You Are Not Welcome')
  }, 5000);
});

doSomethingAsync.then(
  function(message) {
    console.log('After few seconds we can finally tell you:', message)
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log('After few seconds we can finally tell you that: ', error);
  }
);
```

As you can see in the above snippet the **then** method of a **Promise Object** accepts **TWO** params (note, when available, there is a third parameter called **notify** or **progress**), the first is called in case of fullfilment, the second in case of rejection.

While the promise is in **Pending** no callbacks are called!